# limitation on length data that can be sent using $http post

Tags: angularjs

i am using below code for doing http post, but it is failing because of modulusAsHex parameter as length is long.

Is there any limitation on length of data that can be passed

```
 .when('/xyz/abc/step2', {
                    templateUrl: partial('abc.html'),
                    controller: 'abcCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        cardTypeDetails: ['$http','$rootScope', function ($http,$rootScope) {
                            return $http.post(appContext('abc.json'),{"mobilePhoneNumbers":null,"personalCardsOfferedForSelection":[{"nickName":"test card","cardNumberStarred":"**** **** **** 4340","cardNumber":"1223434343434340"}],"selectedCardNumber":null,"modulusAsHex":"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"
                            });
                        }]
                    }

                });
```

modulusAsHex is this long, if I remove this parameter it is working fine any solutions

```
"modulusAsHex":"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"
```

Comment: What webserver is receiving the data?

Comment: And also, what's the exact error?

Comment: @ViktorSarström : Apache Tomcat

Comment: @Chasmo : Error is not showing on browser console, only it is not navigating to abc.html

Comment: Do you have access so you can change the webserver configuration or is it shared hosting?